# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to click on anchor tag and i am using below code for my code execution but i am facing error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" .Please let me know how to fix it.if someone facing the same issue.

```
        $('body').on('mouseover', '.subnav a', function(e) {
            // alert('mouseover event');
            if (window.innerWidth > 723) { //DISCOVERED - this was apparently being used to prevent hover behavior on tablet sized screens, reason unknown. Have now set to mobile breakpoint, consider removing. -TML
                //$(this).click(); //deprecated

                //store tab for delayed display
                Clover.navigation.pendingTab = $(this);
                //clear old timeout
                clearTimeout(Clover.navigation.delayedHoverTimer);
                Clover.navigation.delayedHoverTimer = null;

                //set new timeout. no need to pass var since var now belongs to scope
                Clover.navigation.delayedHoverTimer = setTimeout(function(e) {
                    //alert('delayed trigger fired');
                     try {
                        if (Clover.navigation.pendingTab.attr('class') && Clover.navigation.pendingTab.attr('class').indexOf('prime2') > -1) {
                             return false;
                        } else {
                            Clover.navigation.pendingTab.click();
                                 }

                    } catch (e) {
                       console.log('delayedHover Error: ', e);
                     //Find error on this line
                    }
                }, 100);

            }
        });
        $('body').on('mouseout', '.subnav a', function(e) {
            //clear timeout. clear tab var.
            clearTimeout(Clover.navigation.delayedHoverTimer);
            Clover.navigation.delayedHoverTimer = null;
            Clover.navigation.pendingTab = null;
        });
```

Comment: In general, this means that you're calling a function that ends up calling itself (directly or indirectly), over and over again, until you run out of stack. It's (literally) a Stack Overflow error.

Comment: I don't immediately see that in the above; please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so we can see and help you solve the problem.

Comment: Look at the stack trace in Developer Tools, and see which function is repeatedly calling itself.